# Sony Vaio laptop - What is the magic behind rapid wake and how to migrate to newly bought ssd?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, sony-vaio, partition-recovery

I have vaio [svs13125cgb](https://www.sony.com.sg/electronics/support/laptop-pc-svs-series/svs13125cgb) laptop ( before vaio brand was sold ), I want to buy ssd and replace the hard drive, how do I keep the "rapid wake" feature ( not windows hibernation, not sure how sony did it) and the auto recovery feature on the machine ? ( It has hardware button ASSIST and VAIO next to power button )

I understand that for a UEFI install win10, you usually should have 4 partitions, but my laptop has 3 extra oem partitions as shown in the screenshot below. From the name I guess the third one is related to recovery ? Can I delete the 1st (260 MB) and 2nd one (997 MB)? And this laptop had win8 pre-installed, later upgraded to win10, I guess the recovery data is still win8 in the third oem partition, is there any way I can update the recovery with current win10 ?

[image]

Comment: You should not delete any of those partitions. Please provide the labels for each partition, it is likely, one of them has the GPT label that indicates it is the  `Microsoft Reserved partition`.

Comment: `Microsoft Reserved Partition` is only a default partition with Windows 10, this partition would not have been created, since your device originally came with WIndows 8.

Comment: Rapid wake is nothing more than a sleep mode....http://docs.esupport.sony.com/pc/SVT1111_1311_series/EN/contents/03/12/10/10.html